# Attributes of Face object is always null in firebase ml vision flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-mlkit, mlvision

I followed all the instructions from this [README](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/README.md) for Face detection and When I try to access the attributes of face like `face.leftEyeOpenProbability`,  `face.rightEyeOpenProbability` or `face.smilingProbability` it is throwing me null, **though the faces are detected**.
I tried to approach this in two ways,
1. Using the old firebase_ml_vision plugin for flutter (not compatible with AndroidX)
`firebase_ml_vision: ^0.2.1` where the function `detectInImage()` is used.
2. Using the new firebase_ml_vision plugin (compatible with AndroidX)
`firebase_ml_vision: ^0.6.0+2` where the funciton `processImage()` is used.
In both the approaches **the attributes values are null**.
This is the snippet which uses the latest plugin to detect faces.

```
void _getImageAndDetectFace() async {
  final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  final image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);
  final faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(FaceDetectorOptions(
    mode: FaceDetectorMode.accurate,
    enableLandmarks: true,
  ));
  final faces = await faceDetector.detectInImage(image); //this is not null
  setState(() {
    if (mounted) {
      _imageFile = imageFile;
      _faces = faces;
      for (Face face in faces) { //face is detected here, but...
        print('left eye : ${face.leftEyeOpenProbability}'); //prints null
        print('right eye : ${face.rightEyeOpenProbability}'); //prints null
        print('smiling : ${face.smilingProbability}'); //prints null
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have exactly the same error.

After read the documentation, I found in the class `FaceDetector` the variable `enableClassification`.
This variable has default value False. For use detation of eyes and smiling have to enable this variable.

In your case will be something like this:

```
     ... 
     final faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(FaceDetectorOptions(
        mode: FaceDetectorMode.accurate,
        enableLandmarks: true,
        enableClassification: true
        ));
    ...
```

Hope this helps.